# How to say "one of ten people ..." in Japanese?

Tags: grammar

I want to say

> One of ten people in the world suffers mental disorder.

My attempt but incomplete is as follows,

> 世界のなかに「。。。。」が精神障害に苦しんでいます。

How to say "One of ten people" in Japanese?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can say

> [１０人]{じゅうにん}に[１人]{ひとり}

(「X人にY人」= "Y out of X people" / "Y in every X people")

so

> One of ten people in the world suffers mental disorder.

would be like

> 世界では１０人に１人が精神障害に苦しんでいます。or
>   世界の１０人に１人が精神障害に苦しんでいます。

---

You could also use

> １０人[中]{ちゅう}１人
>   １０人のうち１人

(「X人中Y人」/「X人のうちY人」 = "Y of X people")

as in

> 世界では１０人中１人が精神障害に苦しんでいます。or
>   世界では１０人のうち１人が精神障害に苦しんでいます。

Comment: Sorry, how to say "9 of your friends are just fine"?

Comment: 友達のなかでは九人が大丈夫です。Should do it for Japanese to understand, yet am not sure if it's 100% the way it would be said by a native speaker.

Comment: If you want to say that 9 of the friends are fine but also imply that the others aren't, you could use 友達のなかの九人は大丈夫ですが...

Comment: It literally would be like 「友達**のうち**９人」 but I think you'd normally say 「9人**の**友達」 or 「友達９人」(+ 「は/が元気です」,「は/が大丈夫です」, etc. depending on the context). For this, you don't use に since 「X人にY人」 means "Y in **every** X people".